# Какое максимально-адекватное количество данных я могу подгрузить на фронт за раз?(react)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Я делаю один сайт и, т.к., пока что, не фулстэк, то использую для создания сайта сервис firebase(firestore). И встал вопрос с фильтрами и поиском по сайту. Если фильтры и постраничный вывод я ещё представляю как сделать, то адекватных вариантов поиска в голову не приходит. И вот, я подумал, а можно ли подгрузить за раз записей 200-300 с 7 различными свойствами? Я понимаю, что так делать нехорошо, но если это не сильно повлияет на скорость работы сайта, то это сильно упростило бы мне жизнь. Если что, делаю всё на react.

Answer (score 0):

Это сильно зависит от того, какое соединение использует конечный пользователь.  Если конечный пользователь сидит через 2G, у него просто ничего не загрузится, он будет нервничать и уйдет к конкуренту (и друзьям своим посоветует конкурента, а про разработчика скажет, что он некомпетентен).

Для 2G пределом будет килобайт 50. Чем лучше у пользователя соединение, тем больше вы можете загрузить в него данных.

Comment: В целом, мне лучше самому посмотреть вес приходящих данных + попробовать подгрузить из со скоростью 2g?

Comment: В целом, вам лучше включить gzip/zstd на сервере, чтобы ваши JSON или что вы там льете, удавились на треть